# How convert varchar with quarter date to date format?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have varchar2 (7 BYTE) *PERIOD* column with year and quarter number in format like this:

```
2017-03
```

I need to convert it to date format, but than i try this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(PERIOD, 'YYYY-MM') FROM SCHEM_NAME.TABLE_NAME
```

I get error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
> 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.

I understand that specified number is invalid, but I didn't understand that format I need to try.

Also after I will try to drop all data from table that quarter older than five years from todays date.

Can you explain what is the most appropriate or best way to do this?

I want to use DROP PARTITION something like:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEM_NAME.TABLE_NAME DROP PARTITION
```

**UPDATE:**

Using this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(MAX(PERIOD), 'YYYY-MM') - interval '5' year
FROM SCHEM_NAME.TABLE_NAME
```

I get date from that I need to make drop. As example:

> 01-MAR-17

I need to drop everything that is older than this date. What is the most appropriate way to do this?

Comment: You need to change TO_CHAR(PERIOD, 'YYYY-MM') to TO_DATE(PERIOD, 'YYYY-MM') in your select statement

Comment: Are you sure you are using and want to delete partitions?  Don't you just want to delete data from the table?

Comment: The clue is in the question: *I need to convert it to date*. You need the `to_date` function.

Comment: What date does that represent for you - is it Q3 of the calendar year (so maybe 2017-07-01) or a financial year starting (maybe starting in April, so 2017-10-01), or something else? If your table is partitioned by that string period value then why do you need to convert to a date at all - are you just checking the date it represents is 5 years ago before including that partition in the drop? If so it would be easier to generate a list of period values older than five years?

Comment: @Mahamoutou Now it look like this: SELECT TO_DATE(MAX(PERIOD), 'YYYY-MM')- interval '5' year FROM SCHEM_NAME.TABLE_NAME and it give me the date that I need

Comment: @Mahamoutou as example i get date 01-mar-17 and now I need to drop everything that is older than this date. What is the most appropriate way to do this?

Comment: @AlexPoole it is Q3 of the calendar year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Select:**

As asked, your *PERIOD* column contains the quarter of a year in varchar2.

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEM_NAME.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(PERIOD, 1, Instr(PERIOD, '-', -1, 1) -1) 
  || '-' || 
  LPAD(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(PERIOD, Instr(PERIOD, '-', -1, 1) +1))*3, 2, 0), 'YYYY-MM'), (5*12))) > SYSDATE;
```

**Delete:**

```
DELETE SCHEM_NAME.TABLE_NAME 
WHERE LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(PERIOD, 1, Instr(PERIOD, '-', -1, 1) -1) 
  || '-' || 
  LPAD(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(PERIOD, Instr(PERIOD, '-', -1, 1) +1))*3, 2, 0), 'YYYY-MM'), (5*12))) > SYSDATE;
```

Explanation:

- With Substr, Instr the year and quarter will be extracted from the varchar2 PERIOD.
- LAST_DAY to use the last day of the multiplied month of quarter.
- ADD_MONTHS to add 5 years to *PERIOD* for the condition related to current date (SYSDATE).